# Joining two tables, count counts too high SQL

Tags: sql

I am learning about joining and counting tables in SQL, but I am having some difficulty. Whenever I am joining the tables, the count will skyrocket when it should not be in the first place.

```
select foo.parts as foo_parts, count(foo.colours) 
from  bar, foo
group by foo.parts;
```

The bar table is supposed to be used later to compare "foo.bar" using "having" but I am working on fixing this part first.

Comment: show your schema. what is the structure of bar and foo tables?

Comment: That isa across join and one of the main reasons why you should never use implicit joins. Please stop using this technique that was replaced more than 20 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably are missing the `join` clausule

```
SELECT bar.id, foo.parts as foo_parts, count(foo.colours) 
FROM  bar 
JOIN  foo
  ON  bar.id = foo.id
group by bar.id, foo.parts;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are lacking a lot of information in the question (like how many rows, expected count etc etc). But the syntax

`from bar, foo`

creates a cartesian product which means you get every combination of rows in both tables. It combines every row in bar with every row in foo.

So the expected count is count(bar) * count(foo).

This is very rare in practice. You are probably looking for a conditioned join like Juan suggested.